# Error in Search Scope SharePoint 2010

Tags: search, search-scope, enterprise-search

If I click from Site Action Site Setting and Search Scope I get following message,

> The search service is currently offline. Visit the Services on Server
>   page in SharePoint Central Administration to verify whether the
>   service is enabled. This might also be because an indexer move is in
>   progress.

[image]

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Just deactivate `Document ID Service` and reactivate it.

Source:
[Click Here](http://www.wardpeter.com/?p=989)

Or try this

1. Open central admin
2. Go to Operations
3. Go to Services on server and located your index server
4. On “Office SharePoint Server Search” click “Stop”. This deconfigures it.
5. Now click “start”
6. Then click “Shared Services Administration”, hover over the failing SSP and select edit.
7. You will notice now the indexer is not selected. Select it from the drop down.
8. HERE IS THE IMPORTANT PART. The server you have selected is probably the same server as you used before. If it is, go to that server and locate the indexer files. It is in the textbox right below the drop down you just used. For me it was “F:\Program
   Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Data\Office Server\Applications”. In there you will find a folder with Guid name. At the end of that folder add “_old”. Now go back to your SSP and click OK. Wait 1 minute and the index will recreate the guid folder.
9. Tada, all fixed.

Source: [Click Here](http://waitingimpatiently.com/index.php/2009/07/08/the-search-service-is-currently-offline-visit-the-services-on-server-page-in-sharepoint-central-administration-to-verify-whether-the-service-is-enabled-this-might-also-be-because-an-indexer-move-is/)

Comment: i already did it but its not working

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: @Ashish It appears your answer refers to the Shared Services Provider in 2007, this question is about 2010. Also, you reference the Document ID Service, I don't see the relevance.

Answer (score 0):

Two references I found that might help, are all of your farm machines at the same patch level? If not you may have not properly applied the patches or completed the PSConfig run. On the machines that still need to be upgraded run:

```
psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait
```

The other possibility is that your Alternate Access Mappings are incorrect. Do you have multiple host names for the failing Web Application?